# Adding 26 objects to an array list, but only 13 are being added

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm creating a "Deal or no deal" code assignment for school. I am trying to creating 26 "case" objects in my "cases" arraylist using a for loop, however when I try to test my code it will not let me access anything above index 13. I get an arraylist out of bounds error.

```
public void createCases()
{
    int amount;
    int counter1 = 1;
    int amountFound;
    int allzero;

    //Make a list of possible winning amounts
    int amounts[] = new int[26];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
        amounts[i] = counter1;
        counter1++;
    }

    //Copy the winning amounts from amounts to amountsRandom... randomly.
    int amountsRandom[] = new int[26];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
        do {
            amountFound = (int)(Math.random() * 25);
        } while(amountFound == 0);

        amountsRandom[i] = amounts[amountFound];

        amountFound = 0;
    }

    //Take the amounts in index order and make them part of the case objects in the array list.
    for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
        cases.add(new Case(i++ , amountsRandom[i-1]));
    }
}
```

I declared my cases arraylist outside of this method so it can be accessed by the entire class.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the question as "answered", if it is solved.

Answer (score 4):

You are incrementing `i` twice: once in the `for` loop, once in the constructor call.

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple mistake :P

Answer (score 3):

In your for loop where you add the Case ojects to the cases arraylist

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
    cases.add(new Case(i++, amountsRandom[i-1]));
}
```

You are calling i++ two times, so i will iterate twice per loop. Because of this, it only loops through 13 times instead of 26. You might want to change it to `new Case(i + 1, amountsRandom[i-1])`

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something like that since the number was being cut in half.